# Minimizing the MSE with symmetric scalar quantizers

Tags: electrical-engineering, signal-processing

Let $X$ be a scalar random variable with pdf $f(x)=e^{-2|x|}$. Among the class of symmetric 3 -point scalar quantizers find one which minimizes the MSE in quantizing $X$. Compute the MSE in this case.

I find that f(x) is the Laplacian distribution with  $\mu = 0, b = 1/2$.
By using the Lloyd-max scalar quantizer, I can find that the threshold is $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and quantization levels are $[-1, 0, 1]$.

Now, I need to find
$d=M S E=E\left[(X-\hat{X})^2\right]$, but I can't compute the mean-squared error during integration.

How I can make progress to find the MSE?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$MSE=E\left[(X-\hat{X})^2\right]$$

From the definition of the expectation operator.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(x - \hat{X})^2 f_X(x)} dx$$

Split the integral into the different quantization regions.

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{1}{2}}{(x - (-1))^2 e^{2x}} dx +
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{(x - (0))^2 e^{-2|x|}} dx +
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}{(x - (1))^2 e^{-2x}} dx
$$

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{-\frac{1}{2}}{(x + 1)^2 e^{2x}} dx +
2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{x^2 e^{-2x}} dx +
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}{(x - 1))^2 e^{-2x}} dx
$$

$$
\frac{1}{8}e^{-1} + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{4}e^{-1} \right) + \frac{1}{8}e^{-1}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2} - e^{-1} \approx 0.132
$$